# Show there's an $x^* \neq 0$ such that $\| Ax^*\| = \| A\| \| x^*\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I'm hinted by previous posts that this proof requires the use of the compactness theorem but I don't know how. Could somebody outline such a proof? Again, I am trying to prove that $x^* \neq 0$ such that $\| Ax^*\| = \| A\| \| x^*\|$.

Comment: Since the unit sphere is compact (presumably you're in a finite-dimensional space), so the function $x \to \|Ax\|$ achieves its supremum there.

Comment: Please specify exactly what vector space you're working with here.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is enough to prove it for those  $x $ with  $\|x\|=1$. Then use that the unit sphere, in finite dimension, is compact.